# AngularJS com Single Page e Ng-View não funciona corretamente

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache

Estou utilizando o seguinte material como referência:

http://tableless.com.br/criando-uma-aplicacao-single-page-com-angularjs/

Criei os arquivos com a estrutura apresentada no material para aprender sobre as rotas que o AngularJS disponibiliza e estou colocando os arquivos no diretório root do Apache e o nome do projeto como `rotasangular`, sendo que a URL da aplicação é: `localhost/rotasangular`.

Quando acesso a aplicação funciona normalmente, porém ele tira o nome da aplicação da URL ao acessar a aplicação, ficando apenas `localhost`, além de colocar a URL dessa forma `http://localhost/sobre#%2Fcontato` quando clicamos no link de `Home`, `Sobre` ou `Contatos` impossibilitando que conteúdos de outros arquivos HTML sejam exibidos através das rotas.

**app.js**:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider

    .when ('/', {
        templateUrl: 'rotasangular/views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',

    })

    .when ('/sobre', {
        templateUrl: 'rotasangular/views/contato.html',
        controller: 'ContatoCtrl',
    })

    .when('/contato', {
        templateUrl: 'rotasangular/views/contato.html',
        controller: 'ContatoCtrl',
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

});
```

**controllers.js**:

```
app.controller('HomeCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});

app.controller('SobreCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});

app.controller('ContatoCtrl', function($rootScope, $location)
{
    $rootScope.activetab = $location.path();
});
```

**index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="pt-br" />
    <title>AngularJS: Single Page com ngView e ngRoute</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="{active: activetab == '/'}"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: activetab == '/sobre'}"><a href="#/sobre">Sobre</a></li>
        <li ng-class="{active: activetab == '/contato'}"><a href="#/contato">Contato</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div ng-view></div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="controllers/controllers.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Os outros arquivos HTML não irei postar porque são simples, mas a lógica está acima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não me parece que o problema seja do AngularJS e sim da estrutura do seu diretório . Se você colocou os arquivos no root do Apache ele vai apontar para o root ( / ), tente criar uma pasta chamada *"rotasangular"* no seu root e mova os arquivos da sua aplicação para dentro da pasta.

Abs